# Performance tuning of spark and cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I struggling to tune the spark and cassandra.
I have 10 million of data in cassandra and I am performing operations like read in spark/beeline using spark-cassandra-connector. But it is taking 15-20 min.
I have 4 nodes of cassandra and 3 nodes of sparks. 
Here are my cassandra and spark configurations.

cassandra:

`listen_address: 192.168.xx.xx`
`rpc_address: 192.168.xx.xx`
`endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`
`auto_bootstrap: true`
`start_rpc: true`
`read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000`
`write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000`
`batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 100`
`batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 1000`
`authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator`
`authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer`
`request_timeout_in_ms: 300000`
`range_request_timeout_in_ms: 360000`

Spark:

`spark.master    spark://master:7077`
`spark.cassandra.connection.host 
192.168.xx.xx,192.168.xx.xx,192.168.xx.xx,192.168.xx.xx`
`spark.cassandra.connection.port 9042`
`spark.cassandra.auth.username cassandra`
`spark.cassandra.auth.password cassandra`
`spark.driver.memory              5g`
`spark.executor.memory            6g`
`spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level QUORUM`
`spark.eventLog.enabled true`
`spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer`
`spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb 128`
`spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows 10000`
`spark.sql.qubole.split.computation true`
`spark.sql.inmemorycolumnarstorage.compressed true`

Comment: Based on current information, one can not say if Cassandra is bottleneck or Spark? I suggest to find bottleneck/poorly performing part and then tune it. 
Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460000/spark-streaming-app-stucks-while-writing-and-reading-to-from-cassandra-simultane/45476723#45476723
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132497/having-performance-issues-with-datastax-cassandra/31133715#31133715

Spark performance also needs to be checked but start with monitoring Cassandra and Spark first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I will go through with the mentioned links. I fired one query to count the records it is running since 15 mins. I checked spark job UI, it has created 1122 tasks out of which 1121 are completed and one task is taking time and it is running on only one node. I am not getting why the all other tasks are taking 2-3 min and one task is taking that much of time.

Comment: Execution time for a job depends on processing involved as well as available resources. Check if any heavy operation is done in that job. (For example: such cases can occur when you perform some transformations in earlier jobs and at the end you are writing or transferring final RDD/DF). Check resource util on that single node during last job as well.

Comment: Sharing your spark job snippet or functions which are part of last job will help identify reason behind high execution time.

Comment: `SparkSession spark = new SparkSession.Builder().appName("test").getOrCreate();`
  
`Dataset<Row> selectDF = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
     /**
      * 
      */
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     
{
      
put("keyspace", "testkeyspace");
      
put("table", "rawdata_testing");
     
}
    
}).load().where("kpi='OSA'");`
   
`selectDF.createOrReplaceTempView("temp");`
   
`spark.sql("select count(1) from temp").show();`

this is code snippet.

Comment: @NachiketKate anything that you can share or guide?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at spark stages during execution and find out which stage/task is taking most of the time. Read about reading spark UI and spark documentation for performance improvement. Also read about Spark performance monitoring.